# Will VPN on a mobile device hide location?

Tags: vpn, user-tracking, geolocation, tracking

I have installed a VPN on my phone from a reputable VPN provider (paid VPN service, publicly rated as top 10 globally),

Can my phone location (longitude & latitude) still be traced by third-party apps, or will instead the VPN server location be shared with third-party apps?

I basically want to avoid being tracked in terms of location: is that possible with a VPN on my phone?

Also, is there a difference in how well the VPN works whether I am connected to a WiFi, or whether I am using mobile data?

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of apps.

If you are talking about apps installed on the device, it changes nothing. If they have access to Location data, that data comes from the GPS subsystem on the phone, not from the internet.

If those apps are websites using Location API, it depends on the browser. If the browser have access to location data from the device and you grant location access to the site, it will be the same as before. If the browser or the site does not have location access, it will show geolocation depending on your IP address, and that IP will be your VPN IP.